# Passing default arguments through nested functions in R

Tags: r, function, nested, parameter-passing

I have a general question about passing default arguments through nested functions in R. My example is (obviously) a great simplification of what I actually want to do, but I've had the problem other times so I'm looking for a general solution.

Basically I have three functions, and want some elements to have a default in all three. These functions are called within each other, but sometime called individually (ie `foo1` calls `foo2`, and `foo2` calls `foo3`, but sometimes I call just `foo3` or `foo2`).

Edited to clarify: I am looking for a way to pass `wd` (and in my real problem) a few other variables through from the level of function that is called, without having to write them out in every function call. That is I want to set the default `wd` at all levels. To avoid naming them all different things which is confusing if you want to individually call the functions I tried having `wd = wd` in the function call of each (aiming to access the `wd` from the function it is calling. This gives `promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?`. Is there a better way to pass the argument through so that when called within another function it passing the argument on?

My first example works shows working code, however every time I call the other functions within one I have to specify that `wd = wd`, which when it is a number of arguments, and I am calling the functions multiple times/within `ddply` makes the script cumbersome to work with.

The second example is what I was hoping for, where `wd` is by default set to `wd` in the environment it was called from but this is obviously not allowed the error occurs. What's the best approach to passing the argument without continually having to assign it?

Edit: I have looked at the answer to [promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlie) and I'm aware this is a possible work-around (its how I am currently running the script), but I was really hoping to have the same names for arguments of each function so that when they are called individually it is quick and easy to remember the argument names.

Example 1: works okay but no defaults set.

```
foo1 <- function(x, wd, reps){

  filename = paste0("Event", x)
  myString <- foo2(file = filename, wd = wd)
  rep(myString, reps)
}

foo2 <- function(file,wd){
  filePath <- file.path(wd,file)
  foo3(Path = filePath, wd = wd)
}

foo3 <- function(Path, wd){
  paste("Absolute File path is:", Path, "Current working Dir is:", wd)
}

foo1(1, wd = "c:/temp", 2)
foo2("C:/temp/otherfilename")
```

Example 2:

```
foo2 <- function(file,wd){
  filePath <- file.path(wd,file)
  foo3(Path = filePath)
}

foo3 <- function(Path, wd=wd){
  paste("Absolute File path is:", Path, "Current working Dir is:", wd)
}
foo1(1, wd = "c:/temp", 2)
> Error in paste("Absolute File path is:", Path, "Current working Dir is:",  : 
         promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

Comment: The function definition `foo3 <- function(Path, wd=wd){` is not correct. Something like `foo3 <- function(Path, wd="string"){` should be okay.

Comment: But then I can't automatically pass through what was given as `wd` in `foo2` into `foo3`, which is what I was hoping to achieve

Comment: Suren is correct, the definition is wrong. Of course you can still pass the argument from foo2 to foo3 automatically even if foo3 has a default argument.

Comment: I understand that `wd = wd` doesn't work. My question is what's the best method of passing arguments through which you want to pass to all the nested functions, without having to keep defining them in every function call within the higher level functions?

Comment: I have edited to try and provide more clarity what I am asking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlie)

Comment: it wasnt clear if you want the default value of `wd` to be the global `wd` or the calling function `wd` -- if it's the latter you can check out `parent.frame(wd)`

Comment: wd of the function call so that at any time you can call `foo1(wd = "...", …)` `foo2(wd = "...", …)` etc

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not try to re-use the same name across different environments.  Building off a possibly duplicate question at [promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlie) and some explanation from http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#function-envs:

Why not use a separate name in each function, like this:

```
foo1 <- function(x, wd. = wd, reps){
  filename = paste0("Event", x)
  myString <- foo2(file = filename, wd.. = wd.)
  rep(myString, reps)
}

foo2 <- function(file, wd.. = wd){
  filePath <- file.path(wd.., file)
  foo3(Path = filePath)
}

foo3 <- function(Path, wd... = wd){
  paste("Absolute File path is:", Path, "Current working Dir is:", wd...)
}
```

EDIT in response to comments discussion.  The code below might better accomplish your intent and works with your test calls `foo1(1, wd = "c:/temp", 2)` and `foo2("C:/temp/otherfilename")`:

```
foo1 <- function(x, ..., reps){
  filename = paste0("Event", x)
  myString <- foo2(file = filename, wd = wd)
  rep(myString, reps)
}

foo2 <- function(file, ...){
      filePath <- file.path(wd, file)
  foo3(Path = filePath)
}

foo3 <- function(Path, ...){
  paste("Absolute File path is:", Path, "Current working Dir is:", wd)
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes I had read that question (I should have mentioned it) but was trying to avoid naming them all differently as it makes calling them individually much quicker if you don't have to remember which one to use. That is the work-around I ended up going with, I just thought there might be a smarter/more generally acceptable way as it seems like it would be a common problem.

Comment: Did you get a better solutioin @Sarah? DId you try using `...` in place of the repeated arguments?