# Can't publish R Mardown to Confluence using conflr

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, confluence

I'm trying to post r markdown on Confluence using conflr. 
Once I open the file and click 'Post to Confluence' the knitting process starts and goes all the way to 100% but then I get an error  message (below) and the whole process stops.

followed the steps documented in https://engineering.linecorp.com/en/blog/conflr-published/. I reduced the file to be posted on Confluence to an absolute minimum to try to solve and isolate the error.

I also searched for answers to similar questions here in StackOverflow and on other related resources. However there isn't much documentation available at the moment and could not find an answer.

I tried to post the below text on Confluence form a very simple R markdown file:

```
---
title: "conflr test"
always_allow_html: yes
---
## Overview
Test Test Test
```

Was expecting to get a preview of the page after the knitting process but instead got the below error message:

**output file**: `Conflr_test.knit.md`

> C:/Users/MICHAE~1.EMM/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   Conflr_test.utf8.md --to markdown_strict --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers-tex_math_single_backslash-tex_math_dollars-raw_tex
>   --output Conflr_test.md --standalone --wrap=none

**Output created:** `Conflr_test.md`

> Error in conflr:::confl_create_post_from_Rmd() :    promise already
>   under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier
>   problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlier you may want to take a look at this