# Function with default arguments and ... throws Error in dots_list(...) : promise already under evaluation

Tags: r, ellipsis

I have a function wih default arguments and ... like the following:

```
library(shiny)
foo <- function(id = NULL, title = "Title",
                icon = icon("caret-right"),
                ...) {
  tags$div(class = "divcl", id = id,
           tags$h3(class = "hea", title,
                   tags$span(class = "spancl", icon)),
           ...)
}
```

Everything works fine as long as long as I call it with `id` and `icon` like:

```
foo(id = "id", icon = icon("cars"), tags$div())
```

But when I want to use the default arguments of `icon` and `title` like:

```
foo(id = "id", tags$div())
```

I am getting this error:

> Error in dots_list(...) :    promise already under evaluation:
>   recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlie

Answer (score 1):

Remember that R matches arguments by name or by position.

Since the argument you pass (i.e., `tags$div()`) is unnamed, it is used as the first argument that is not matched by name. This is `title` in both cases.

You can verify that by placing a `browser()` statement at the top of your function, call it, and then type `title` or `list(...)` at the console.

You can resolve this by either passing only named arguments to functions using `...`. Or by rearranging the order of the arguments in the function definition.

Last, note that only one of your calls errors because, ..., well, you have an argument of the form `icon = icon`; see [promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4357101/2563804).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use named arguments for ...  as there might be a lot of div-tags or whatever HTML which. I am not 100% following the rearranging approach. Is there a way to make the 2nd example work, without changing argument names?

Comment: You would have to pass all other arguments of the function, e.g., `foo(id = "id", icon = icon("cars"), title = "Some title", tags$div())`.

Comment: Hm, yeah thats what I was doing until now, but I was hoping, that I could use the default arguments of the function.

Comment: If you want to use unnamed arguments, they will always be matched by position. As an alternative, you could combine all currently named arguments into a list---making this a single argument---, and then used `...` as the second argument.