# Simple syntax question regarding "f." in R

Tags: r, syntax

I was reading this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357101/promise-already-under-evaluation-recursive-default-argument-reference-or-earlie), and the solution given was this block of `R` code:

```
f <- function(x, T) {
   10 * sin(0.3 * x) * sin(1.3 * x^2) + 0.001 * x^3 + 0.2 * x + 80 
}

g <- function(x, T, f. = f) {  ## 1. note f.
   exp(-f.(x)/T) 
}
 
test<- function(g. = g, T = 1) {  ## 2. note g.
   g.(1,T) 
}
 
test()
## [1] 8.560335e-37
```

I would just like a little explanation of the syntax in the function definitions of `g` and `test`, where the author notes `f.` and `g.` I've seen things like `.f` and `.g` as when using `map` or something like that, but I haven't seen the `.` come after. I've tried Googling but my inability to identify really what it was led to poor results. I believe it has something to do with recursion? I don't actually know.

Comment: I believe what you're seeing is the difference between what is referred to as a function versus a 'functional.' The dot is to identify that the parameter is not an object (as in a variable), but that it is another function. The use of .f in something like `map` is coded as the input parameter. Whereas in base R, a function as a parameter is called using `f.` (or whatever the function's name is).

Comment: @Kat Do you have an example where base R uses suffix dots specifically for function arguments? They generally don’t, and a I can’t think of any example. Most use either `FUN` or just regular function names (e.g `f`). Anyway, your comment is potentially misleading because it implies that parameters bound to functions aren’t variables but of course they *are* regular variables. And ‘purrr’ *also* doesn’t use prefix-dot to denote functions — it just uses dots for *all* arguments, in an (IMHO misguided) attempt to disambiguate them from named arguments forwarded via `...`.

Comment: @Kat I actually got curious so I looked at *all* function arguments in base R ([using a script](https://pastebin.com/ZDSasx6e)). There are *no* instances of function parameters referring to functions that end in `.`. There are some parameter names that end in `.` (e.g. the `call.` parameter in `stop`) but none of them bind to functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot at the end has no effect on the syntax, it's just like any other legal character in an identifier.  A dot at the beginning has very little effect, but it does mean `ls()` won't display the variable by default.

In the examples you posted, the author probably used `f.` to remind the reader that the default value was `f`, and `g.` reminds the reader of `g`.

Partial argument matching means that a user could write `test(g = somefn)` and R would treat `somefn` as the value of the `g.` argument.

In the referenced question where you saw this code, the original function had header

```
g <- function(x, T, f=f) {
```

This won't work, because the default value has the same name as the argument, and defaults are evaluated in the frame of the function.  So it says "If the argument `f` is not specified, set it to the argument `f`."  That makes no sense.  The corrected version that you posted says "If the argument `f.` is not specified, set it to the global variable `f`."